# What is the best way to save ChaCha20 Nonce in Cipher-Image BMP file?

Tags: encryption, stream-cipher, decryption, chacha

I have a question about ChaCha20. As far as I know ChaCha20 is a cipher algorithm that uses 4 inputs:

1. Key (secret)
2. Constant (not secret)
3. Block Number/Counter (keystream block number)
4. Nonce (random number per encryption/key & considered non-secret)

My question is how do I store a 12-byte (96-bit) ChaCha20 Nonce on a Cipher-Image/CipherText, specifically a BMP file?

[image: illustration]

I want to do this so that the Cipher-Image can be decrypted by other users using the same key & nonce when the Plaint-Image was encrypted before.

I know that BMP has a dedicated header space of approximately 54-bytes and thought to put Nonce in it. But I doubt if this won't interfere with the header file information already in the Plaint-Image.

I'm also thinking of putting a 12-byte Nonce at the end of the file, but I doubt whether the file will still be read by the image viewer application (cmiiw).

What is the most appropriate solution for this problem?

Comment: Putting nonce at the end works with standard Ubuntu viewers :-) Or perhaps you could append to the filename in hex?

Comment: You may still face the issue of authentication if you (kinda) roll your own crypto...

Comment: Is there any particular reason the cipher text has to be a valid `.bmp`?  You can always use a cleverer viewer like `ImageMagick` or `GIMP` to load the ciphertext as raw pixel values. All cipher text kinda looks the same, anyway. Important bonus of doing it my way: you can use standard encryption libraries that you can be certain of working securely, and the authentication issue is resolved.

Comment: @Paul Uszak. Thank you for your advice. Actually I just want if the BMP file can be opened by the built-in image viewer which is widely used, like in Windows 7 & 10. (Considering the number of users).